# passing function calls in scala as arguments, does function evaluate first?

Tags: scala, recursion, tail-recursion

I was just playing around with a implementation of foldlLeft in Scala

```
def foldLeft[A,B] (as: List[A], z: B) (f: (B, A) => B): B = as match {
  case Nil => z
  case Cons(x, xs) => foldLeft(xs, f(z,x)) (f)
}
```

In this implementation, `f(z,x)` is in the recursive call given as parameter for `z`, but I was wondering how this actually works?
When the recursive call happens, does `foldLeft()` receive the value of the execution of `f(z,b)` or does it receive the function call the way it is written, and then execute when needed?

Example:
if we call `foldLeft()` with the following values

```
def foldLeft[A,B] ([1,2,3], 0) (f: (x, y) => x + y): B = as match {
  case Nil => z
  case Cons(x, xs) => foldLeft([2,3], f(0,1)) (f)
}
```

Will the next execution of `foldLeft()` like this, where z is equal to the value of `f()`?

```
def foldLeft[A,B] ([2,3], 1) (f: (x, y) => x + y): B = as match {
  case Nil => z
  case Cons(x, xs) => foldLeft([2,3], f(1,2)) (f)
}
```

or does it work like this, where `foldLeft()` receives the call itself?

```
def foldLeft[A,B] ([2,3], f(0,1)) (f: (x, y) => x + y): B = as match {
  case Nil => z
  case Cons(x, xs) => foldLeft([3], f(f(1,0),2)) (f)
}
```

The question is essentially about when the values that a tail recursive function are evaluated?

Comment: `z` is of type **B**, as such you can only pass a **B**, not a function, not a by-name parameter, not anything else; just a plain **B**. Also, `f(z,x)` is an evaluation of the function, it will be executed before anything else _(remember **Scala** is an eager language, not a lazy one like **Haskell**)_ to produce the **B**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scala, like almost every mainstream language, is a *strict* language with an *eager* evaluation strategy and *pass-by-value* argument passing semantics.

This means that [all arguments to a method or function call will be fully evaluated before being passed into the method or function](https://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/06-expressions.html#function-applications).

However, what I wrote is actually not quite true: that is only the *default*.

There are two ways to deviate from the default:

1. The [`lazy` modifier](https://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/05-classes-and-objects.html#lazy) makes a value, well, lazy.
2. [*by-name* parameters](https://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/04-basic-declarations-and-definitions.html#by-name-parameters) are passed by name, not by value.

#1 is not applicable here. #2 needs to be explicitly declared in the parameter list, which is not the case here.

Therefore, we can conclude that, yes, `f(z, x)` will be fully evaluated before the recursive call to `foldLeft`.